# Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(F)I in java

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying migrade my project java 1.5 to java 1.6 and i am using Jboss 4.2 server while starting of server I am facing below error please any one help to me.

my system configuration is dualcore processor and 3GB ram

```
enter code here

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(F)I
at java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(Native Method)
at java.lang.Math.<clinit>(Math.java:801)
at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.lowMask(ParseUtil.java:512)
at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.<clinit>(ParseUtil.java:559)
at sun.misc.Launcher.getFileURL(Launcher.java:388)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtURLs(Launcher.java:165)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.<init>(Launcher.java:137)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run(Launcher.java:121)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtClassLoader(Launcher.java:118)
at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:51)
at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:39)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1304)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1286) ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the jdk6 variant of JBoss built (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss/JBoss-4.2.3.GA/jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip/download)

Comment: @erraveni: you shouldn't post followup questions as answers. I'd recommend to format & post it as a separate question